# Difference between "go run", "go build" and "go install"

Tags: go

What are the differences between "go run", "go build" and "go install" and in which cases I should use them?

Comment: What is unclear in the documentation you get from `go help run`, `go help build` and `go help install`?

Comment: @Volker I am not able to understand the usecase

Comment: `go install` compiles packages and binaries and stores them in $GOPATH/pkg and $GOPATH/bin. `go build` builds packages and discards the result, for binaries it builds and keeps the executable. `go run` is a handy shortcut to build some code and run it directly.

Comment: Checkout all command official documentation on https://golang.org/cmd/go/